# Django admin for User changes Groups widget when I add a custom admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to use the out-of-the-box User model in Django, but add an action to the admin.

Without any custom admin, the User's admin has this many-to-many control for groups:

[image: default groups]

But when I register a custom Admin:

```
class CustomModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  actions = ['custom_action']

  def custom_action(self, request, queryset):
    pass

  custom_action.short_description = "Custom Action"

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomModelAdmin)
```

The control changes to a simpler select. I want the original one, as my list of groups may get large.

[image: simple select]

Why did it change? How do restore it to the former?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I was subclassing the vanilla ModelAdmin which didn't include User customisations. Modifying my class to extend `django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin` does the job.